# ansible untar a file on a windows target

Tags: windows, ansible, tar

I have been trying to untar a file .tar with ansible on a windows target using module "win_unzip" below and it doesn't work.

```
- name: Unzip fichero
  community.windows.win_unzip:
    src:  /some_user/test-ansible/fake_package.tar
    dest: /some_user/test-ansible/
```

*Note: That module "win_unzip" works just fine to unzip of course .zip files*

ERROR MSG
The msg displays that PSCX is needed but it is already there, otherwise "win_unzip" won't work with .zip files.

```
TASK [Unarchive a file that is already on the remote machine] *********************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [wintrg-01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": "C:\\Users\\some_user\\Desktop\\", "msg": "PowerShellCommunityExtensions PowerShell Module (PSCX) is required for non-'.zip' compressed archive types.", "removed": false, "src": "C:\\Users\\some_user\\Desktop\\fake_package.tar"}
```

I think that maybe I would need to install 7zip in the windows target and use ansible module "win_shell" to untar the required file.

Are you aware of any ansible community module that can do this?.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWERING TO MYSELF**

I did the 7z install, "set environmental variable", then used "win_shell", passed the command with flag "-y" and it worked.

**Anyways I still wonder if there is some ansible module to deal with .tar files on Windows targets.**

```
- name: 'testing zip copy and unzip'
  hosts: wintrg-01
  tasks:
    - name: Untar file
      ansible.windows.win_shell: "7z e -y fake_package.tar"
      args:
        chdir: C:\Users\somer_user\Desktop
```